# Will standard units be affected by multiplying a negative constant?

Tags: statistics

[image]

So I'm reasonably sure that for part (a) the standard unit won't change because we basically only multiplied the numbers in list 1 by 2 and added a constant 1.

For part (B) though, I just want to make sure my rationale is correct.

the operation that we would have to do to get the numbers in (ii) is we multiply -2 then add 1 to every number in (i).

My intuition tells me that when we multiply a negative number this changes the SU compare to the numbers in list (i) right?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Here's an intuition pump: Convert $1, 2, 6$ and $-1, -2, -6$ to standard units and compare. ($1, 2, 6$ has mean $3$ and SD $\sqrt{7}$.)

Answer (score 1):

At $a)$ we have two lists 1. and 2. Each of the data can be converted to standard units:

$$x_{ij}^*=\frac{x_{ij}-\overline x_j}{\sigma_j}$$

$i$ is the index for the i-th value. $j$ is the index for `list 1` or `list 2`.

Let $\overline x_1$ the average from list 1. From the text below you can evaluate that at $a)$ the average from `list 2` is

$\overline x_2=2 \overline x_1+1 \quad (1)$

And the standard deviation is $\sigma_2=2\sigma_1 \quad (2)$

The converted values (standard units) has to be equal

$$\frac{x_{i1}-\overline x_1}{\sigma_1}=\frac{x_{i2}-\overline x_2}{\sigma_2}$$

Now we can insert the expression for $\overline x_2$ and $\sigma_2$ from (1) and (2) and see if the equation is equal. For this purpose we take the first values from list 1 and list 2: $x_{11}=1, x_{12}=3$

$$\frac{1-\overline x_1}{\sigma_1}=\frac{3-(2\overline x_1+1)}{2\sigma_1}$$

Are the two expressions equal? If yes, then the two lists 1 and 2 are equal after conversion. The same can be done at $b)$.

---

At $b)$ the  average of the converted data is

$\overline x^c=-2\overline x+1$

It is related to the expected value for random variables:

$\mathbb E(aX+b)=a\cdot \mathbb E(X)+b$

In general we have the empirical variance $\hat s^2(x)$. Then $\hat s^2(ax+b)=a^2\cdot \hat s^2(x)$

It is related to the formula for random variables: $Var(aX+b)=a^2\cdot Var(X)$

Thus in b) the variance of the converted data is four-times ($a^2= (-2)^2$) of the variance of the original data since $a=-2$. Therefore the standard deviation double: $\sqrt{4}=2$ . We see the negative sign of the factore doesn´t change sign of the standard deviation.

---

Comment: I get that SD doesn't change, but I'm wondering about the Standard Units

Comment: @pino231 At b)  the standard deviation (SD) of the converted units is **twice** the SD of the standard units. It is not asked for a value of SD of  the standard units.

Comment: oh yes that's correct the SD is multiplied by 2, but so was the average so that essentially cancels out right? but the negative sign does change the SU doesn't it?

Comment: I don´t understand what do you mean by "but so was the average so that essentially cancels out right? " Please forumlate in a more comprehensible way.

Comment: What I meant to say is that when we multiply the entire list by 2 both the SD and Average increase by 2 times of their original values, therefore the standard unit doesn't really change. However, if we multiply every number by a negative number then, the average does change therefore the standard unit also changes as a result right?

Comment: @pino231 I recognized that I haven´t fully understood the exercise. Sorry for that. But I got it now. Please read the edited anwer. I left one part of my previous answer since it is still relevant for calcualting the average and the standard deviation.